How do I prevent Azure BICEP deployment "unexpected InternalServerError"
I have a large, complex Azure BICEP deployment script. It works 100%, however I get an intermittent transient error from Azure.
    {
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "target": "/subscriptions/xx-xx-xx-xx-xx/resourceGroups/xx-xx-rg-tst-xx-eus-99/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/webAppSubCreateWeb-xx-xx-app-xx-tst-aty-eus-99-dev",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InternalServerError",
      "message": "There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: xxxx"
    }
  ]
}

The error will always happen when deploying a web app from an string array; it's not always the same web app. A lot of times there is no error.
Am I doing anything wrong? Can I do anything better to protect my deployment from InternalServerError?
'main'
@batchSize(6)
module webAppSubCreateApi 'webAppSubCreate.bicep' = [for (web,i) in webApplicationsToCreateApi: {
  name: 'webAppSubCreateApi-${web}'
  params: {
    location: location
    createAppServicePlanId: createAppServicePlanApi.id
    identityId: identity.id
    vnetSubNetId: vnetSubNetId
    webapp: web
    appInsightsConnectionString: appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
  }
  dependsOn: [createAppServicePlanApi, identity, workspace]
}]

Module
param webapp string
param location string
param identityId string
param createAppServicePlanId string
param vnetSubNetId string
param appInsightsConnectionString string

//create web app instances, one for each web application in the list webApplicationsToCreate
resource createWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-01-01' =  { 
  name: webapp
  location: location
  kind: 'windows'
  identity: {
    type:'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identityId}': {}     
    }  
  }
    properties: {
      httpsOnly: true
      serverFarmId: createAppServicePlanId
      reserved: false     
      vnetRouteAllEnabled: false
      siteConfig:{
        alwaysOn:true        
        netFrameworkVersion: '6.0'
        metadata:[
        {
          name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
          value: 'dotnet'
        }
        {
          name: 'netFrameworkVersion'
          value: 'v6.0'
        }               
      ]  
      appSettings:[
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: appInsightsConnectionString
        }
      ]         
    }    
    virtualNetworkSubnetId:vnetSubNetId    
  }
}

output webappparentname string = createWebApp.name


I would try setting the batchSize to 1 and see it if makes it more stable. I've ran into similar issues while running simultaneous deployments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187263/azure-deployment-failing-with-internalservererror please check with this once @Damo


Prevent Azure BICEP deployment "unexpected InternalServerError

Issue mainly seems to be due to when youre trying to deploy resources simultaneously using bicep.
As d1-1  suggested it was always a best practice to use less batch count as it directly effects the efficiency of deployment.
I tried the same and able to achieve the deployment successfully without any blocker mentioned.
main.bicep:
param location string = 'eastus'
param appServicePlanSku string = 'P1v2'
param appInsightsLocation string = 'eastus'

var webAppNames = [
  'webAppDemo1vk'
  'webAppDemo2vk'
  'webAppDemo3vk'
]

resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: 'appInsightsDemo'
  location: appInsightsLocation
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'appServicePlanDemo'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: appServicePlanSku
    tier: 'PremiumV2'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

@batchSize(2)
module webApps 'webApp.bicep' = [for webAppName in webAppNames: {
  name: 'webAppModule-${webAppName}'
  params: {
    location: location
    appServicePlanId: appServicePlan.id
    appInsightsConnectionString: appInsights.properties.ConnectionString
    webAppName: webAppName
  }
}]

output appServicePlanId string = appServicePlan.id

webapp.bicep:
param location string
param appServicePlanId string
param appInsightsConnectionString string
param webAppName string
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'app'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlanId
    httpsOnly: true
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: appInsightsConnectionString
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
output webAppName string = webApp.name

Deployment:
run the command
az deployment group create --resource-group rg name --template-file main.bicep



Refer:
Azure Bicep - Deployment Failed (Conflict) Another operation on this or dependent resource is in progress (AnotherOperationInProgress) by Thomas
Create an App Service app using Azure Bicep - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn
